# OpenCart, Category page, Price minus Special (SAVE!!)

Tags: categories, opencart

I would like to add a 'Save' Box to the categories page (category.tpl/php), but have made many efforts to do this and failed.  Have you done this? Do you know how to do this? Can you help?

Price - Special = Save

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something similar was asked earlier on today. Is this what you mean?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7897686/showing-discounted-amount-and-percentage-on-products-in-opencart

Comment: The problem turned out to be the £ sign in the value returned.

Comment: Yeah, when the prices are passed to the template file from the controller, they're formatted with currency symbols and thousand separator commas if applicable. That's due to the fact that any calculations like the one you wanted should really be handled by the controller, and passed over to the template as it does natively, but does make some simple template tweaks awkward